# Exercise 6.50 in Bott Tu Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

The problem asks to show that
$$H^k(f^*) \simeq H^k(g^*)$$
For homotpic maps $f$ and $g$.
Where, given a map $f:M\to S$, $H^k(f^*)$ is defined by first defining the complex $\Omega^k(f^*) = \Omega^k(M)\oplus\Omega^{k-1}(S)$ and then the differential operator $d_f:\Omega^k(f^*)\to\Omega^{k+1}(f^*)$ by
$$d_f(\omega,\theta) = (d\omega,f^*\omega-d\theta)$$

Since $\Omega^k(f^*) = \Omega^k(g^*) = \Omega^k(M)\oplus\Omega^{k-1}(S)$, it seems to me that the proof should involve showing that $\ker(d_f) = \ker(d_g)$ and $\text{Im}(d_f) = \text{Im}(d_g)$.

Working from Corollory 4.1.2 (homotopic maps induce the same maps in cohomology) gives
$$f^*\omega = g^*\omega + d\lambda$$
for any closed form $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$ ($\lambda\in\Omega^{k-1}(S)$). From here, I can show the images are the same, since
$$d_f(\omega,\theta) = (d\omega,f^*\omega-d\theta) = (d\omega,g^*\omega-d(\theta-\lambda)) = d_g(\omega,\theta-\lambda)$$
and so any form in the image of $d_f$ is also in the image of $d_g$ and vice versa, but I cannot seem to get a similar result on the kernels, instead, all I get is that if $d_f(\omega,\theta) = 0$, then $d_g(\omega,\theta) = (0,-d\lambda).$

Comment: Your map $f$ should go from $S$ to $M$, not the other way round. Note that you are supposed to show that $H^k(f^{\ast})\cong H^k(g^{\ast})$, but it is not claimed that this isomorphism is induced by the identity on the representatives, which is what your current approach would be showing. Indeed, your calculation shows that this cannot be the case. So, instead, perhaps consider a map $\Omega(f^{\ast})\rightarrow\Omega(g^{\ast})$ that "twists" elements precisely by the deficiency $\lambda$ you notice in your proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Noting that $d\lambda=f^*\omega-g^*\omega$ defines $d\lambda$ as a linear function of $\omega$, I defined $\psi(\omega,\theta) = (\omega,\theta-\lambda(\omega))$. From here I managed to show $\psi$ is an isomorphism provided it is linear, which relies on the linearity of $\lambda$, which I cannot see how to do. $d\lambda$ is clearly linear, but I cannot think of how to show that this is sufficient for the existence of a linear map $\lambda:\Omega^k(M)\to\Omega^{k-1}(S)$ with $d(\lambda(\omega))=d\lambda(\omega)$. I can see there is one, but not that there is a linear one

Comment: This is the correct observation. Note that $\lambda$ is not uniquely determined by $\omega$, so the point is really that there is a *choice* of $\lambda$ for each $\omega$, which is linear. This is possible, because we don't "just" know that $f^{\ast}$ and $g^{\ast}$ induce the same map on cohomology, but actually that $f^{\ast}$ and $g^{\ast}$ are chain homotopic. In fact, the map $\lambda$ you seek is precisely the same thing as a chain homotopy between $f^{\ast}$ and $g^{\ast}$.

Answer (score 2):

(ended up posting this as an answer since it turned out so long)

I think I managed to do it. Going back to the proof of the Poincaré lemmas in the book, they show that the composition of the $0\text{-section}$ $s_0$ with the projection $\pi$ on $M\times\mathbb{R}$ is chain homotopic to the identity
$$\mathbb{1} - \pi^*\circ s_0^* = (-1)^{q-1}(dK - Kd)$$
where they define $K$ as integration of over fibres. First, one can extend this to any constant $r\in\mathbb{R}$ section $s_r$ by altering the definition of $K$ so that its action on type II forms from
$$(\pi^*\phi)f(x,t)dt\mapsto(\pi^*\phi)\int_0^t f$$
to
$$(\pi^*\phi)f(x,t)dt\mapsto(\pi^*\phi)\int_r^t f$$
This then allows us to write
$$\mathbb{1}-\pi^*\circ s_r^* = (-1)^{q-1}(dK_r - K_rd)$$
With $K_r$ following the new definition.

From here, we note that
\begin{align}
\pi^*\circ(s_0^*-s_1^*) &= \pi^*\circ s_0^* - \pi^*\circ s_1^*\\
& = -(\mathbb{1}-\pi^*\circ s_0^*)+(\mathbb{1}- \pi^*\circ s_1^*)\\
& = -(-1)^{q-1}(dK_0-K_0d)+(-1)^{q-1}(dK_1-K_1d)\\
& = (-1)^{q-1}\big(dK_1-dK_0-K_1d+K_0d\big)\\
& = (-1)^{q-1}\big(d(K_1-K_0)-(K_1-K_0)d\big).
\end{align}

Now, recalling that if the homotopy map  is $F:M\times\mathbb{R}\to M$ ($F(x,0)=f(x)$, $F(x,1)=g(x)$), that
$$f^* = (F\circ s_0)^* = s_0^*\circ F^*$$
$$g^* = (F\circ s_1)^* = s_1^*\circ F^*$$
and also, that for any section $s$, $\pi\circ s = id$, the identity map on $M$, so that
$$s^*\circ\pi^* = (\pi\circ s)^* = (id)^* = \mathbb{1}$$

We see that
\begin{align}
f^*-g^* &= s_0^*\circ F^* - s_1^*\circ F^*\\
& = (s_0^* - s_1^*)\circ F^*\\
& = s^*\circ\pi^*\circ(s_0^* - s_1^*)\circ F^*\\
& = s^*\circ(-1)^{q-1}\big(d(K_1-K_0)-(K_1-K_0)d\big)\circ F^*\\
& = (-1)^{q-1}\bigg(d\Big(s^*\circ(K_1-K_0)\circ F^*\Big)-\Big(s^*\circ(K_1-K_0)\circ F^*\Big)d\bigg)
\end{align}
since pullbacks commute with the differential.

All this leads to an explicit form for a linear $\lambda$, namely
$$\lambda = s^*\circ(K_1-K_0)\circ F^*$$
where $F$ is the homotopy between $f$ and $g$, the $K$'s are integration over the fibres, and $s$ is any arbitrary section.